# assign a shorter column to a longer column, given a sliding winow

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe `df1` of 8 rows:

```
ID

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

And I have this array `arr` of size 4 `[-1, 0, 1, 2]`, and an `m = 2`, so I want to assign the values of this array jumping `m` times to `df1`, so I can have eventually:

```
ID      N

A      -1
B      -1 
C       0
D       0
E       1
F       1
G       2
H       2
```

How to do that in Python?

Comment: Hi, you have to add some sample codes to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']})
arr=[-1,0,1,2]
m=2
```

If `arr` should be repeated again and again:

```
df1['N']=(arr*m)[:len(df1)]
```

Result:

|  | ID | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | -1 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 3 | D | 2 |
| 4 | E | -1 |

If each element should be repeated:

```
df1['N']=[arr[i] for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(m)][:len(df1)]
```

Result:

|  | ID | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | -1 |
| 1 | B | -1 |
| 2 | C | 0 |
| 3 | D | 0 |
| 4 | E | 1 |

Comment: This is wrong. The output of your code is `[-1,0,1,2,-1,0,1,2]` while OP wanted `[-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

~~ Without numpy

```py
arr = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
m = 2
df1["N"] = sum([[x]*m for x in arr], [])
```

~~ With Numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
m = 2
df1["N"] = np.repeat(arr, m)
```

Output:

```
    ID  N
0   A   -1
1   B   -1
2   C   0
3   D   0
4   E   1
5   F   1
6   G   2
7   H   2
```